# Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto = update

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

We are using hibernate3.jar.The hibernate property was set as below,

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Added new column in the existing table and Migrated our application from old to new release. The column was added successfully in the table after migration but facing below errors in the log:

```
> ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 314) Unsuccessful: alter table TEST add column source_id int
> default 0  ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 314) Duplicate column name 'source_id'
```

The column was added successfully but still facing the errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

It's [known issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9849) for Hibernate. Use the [latest Hibernate vesion](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate) instead of hibernate3.jar.